# Find specific quantities within a vector or within a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I need to identify the time at which the following values occur, namely: eta = 0 and eta = 0:51;

I should work with 'find' code, but could not get desired value.
I know how it works in 'maximum':

```
t = -10:1:10;
t = t';
eta = -t .^2;
ind = find (eta == max(eta));
t_etamax = t(ind ,1);
t_etamax = t(ind ,1);
eta_max = eta (ind ,1);
```

Now I need not Maximum but when eta=0 and eta=0.51

Comment: Did you try a simple `find(eta==0)`?

Comment: Maybe the last statement in the question is ambiguous: do you need to calculate 1) the max when `eta=0` and then another max when `eta=0.51`?
or 2) the max for both groups (i.e. when `eta=0 || eta=0.51`)? Also note that in your example the value `0.51` is not present in the `eta` vector.

Comment: sorry, I mean `eta=0 | eta=0.51`